Bound on the min of the sum of cosines at two rationally related frequencies
I am interested in the minima of the sum of two frequencies:
\begin{equation}
\Delta = \min_t\left[\cos(t) + \delta \cos\left(\frac{p}{q}t+\phi\right)\right]
\end{equation}
$\phi, \delta\in\mathbb{R}$, and $p$ and $q$ are integers in their simplest form (i.e. if they both share a factor, for example are both even, divide out that factor of 2 first), and neither of which is 1. I think that, for all choices of $\phi, \delta, p$ and $q$:
\begin{equation}
\Delta^2 > 1 + \delta^2
\end{equation}
This has good numerical backing. Can you help me to prove it?

P. S. My best attempt so far is for $\phi=0$, but might point to some useful directions for generalising. It involves guessing extreme values of $t$ to show $\Delta$ must be at least this big, inspired by https://mathoverflow.net/questions/209071/maximal-minimum-for-a-sum-of-two-or-more-cosines.
Assume $p$ and $q$ are odd, and $\delta>0$, then take $t = q\pi$:
\begin{equation}
\cos(t) + \delta \cos\left(\frac{p}{q}t\right) = -1-\delta
\end{equation}
Therefore $\Delta^2 > (1+\delta)^2>1+\delta^2$.
Conversely, if one of $p$ or $q$ is even (let's say $p$) (according to definition of $p$ and $q$ they cannot both be even), and $\delta < 0$, again choose $t=q\pi$:
\begin{equation}
\cos(t) + \delta \cos\left(\frac{p}{q}t\right) = -1-|\delta|
\end{equation}
Therefore $\Delta^2 > (1+|\delta|)^2>1+\delta^2$.
Now for some more involved argumentation. If one of $p$ or $q$ is even and $\delta>0$, then there is an odd integer $k$ such that:
\begin{equation}
kp = q+1 \quad \mod 2q
\end{equation}
Take $t=k\pi$, then for some integer $n$
\begin{equation}
\cos(t) + \delta \cos\left(\frac{p}{q}t\right) = \cos(k\pi) + \delta \cos\left(\frac{q+1+2nq}{q}\pi\right) = -1-\delta\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{q}\right)
\end{equation}
In order that $\Delta^2 < 1+\delta^2$ we can find a condition on $\delta$:
\begin{equation}
\delta \geq \frac{2\cos(\frac{\pi}{q})}{1-\cos^2(\frac{\pi}{q})}
\end{equation}
Applying a similar argument but with $t=\frac{qk\pi}{p}$ we get a similar inequality:
\begin{equation}
\delta \leq \frac{1-\cos^2(\frac{\pi}{p})}{2\cos(\frac{\pi}{p})}
\end{equation}
Squeezing these two inequalities together you find that in order for such a $\delta$ to exist:
\begin{equation}
1\leq \frac{(1-\cos^2(\frac{\pi}{p}))(1-\cos^2(\frac{\pi}{q}))}{4\cos(\frac{\pi}{p})\cos(\frac{\pi}{q})}
\end{equation}
Which cannot be satisfied for an odd-even $p$, $q$ pair with both not equal to 1.
The final case, both $p$ and $q$ odd and $\delta<0$ can be done with a similar approach but using an even integer $k$ in the congruence equation.
To generalise this to arbitrary phase $\phi$, we just need to work out how to appropriately shift the $t$ we choose to make similar proofs go through...
